# AngularJS multiselect with hardcoded options doesn't update when model does

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multi-select element that is generated with values outside of Angular's control. In effect this creates some static html options inside the select that I would like to control from angular. The problem is that when the model is first initialised (from a deferred function), all the other variables get updated on the page, but the select doesn't. When I select an item in the list, it shows the correct values selected (including the one coming from the load that should have been selected first). The html looks like this:

```
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" id="roles" ng-model="model.userRoles">
    <option value="Owner" >owner</option>
    <option value="Driver">driver</option>
    <option value="Lessee">lessee</option>
</select>
```

Where model.userRoles is an array of strings matching the values. Why doesn't the selection update when I assign the array?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `ngModel` [compares by reference and not by value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select). The way you are trying to use the `<select>` element is unfortunately incompatible with how Angular's built in directive works.

Your best option (no pun intended) is to use the built in [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) to populate the dropdown:

```
//inside your controller:
this.roles = ['Owner','Driver','Lessee'];

<!-- in your markup (assumes 'Controller As' -->
<select multiple="multiple" 
        ng-options="role for role in ctrl.roles"
        ng-model="ctrl.userRoles" >
</select>
```

This way, Angular will track the individual options as values and updates to the underlying model will be updated accordingly.

**And just to be thorough, here is a working example for you to look at.**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function SimpleController($timeout) {
    this.roles = ['Owner', 'Driver', 'Lessee'];
    this.userRoles = [];
    
    //Simulate service call
    $timeout(function(){
    
      this.userRoles.push('Owner');
      this.userRoles.push('Driver');
      
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }
  
  SimpleController.$inject = ['$timeout'];

  angular.module('my-app', [])
    .controller('simpleCtrl', SimpleController);

}());
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="simpleCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="row">
    <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" ng-options="role for role in ctrl.roles" ng-model="ctrl.userRoles">
    </select>
  </div>
  <h2>User Roles</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well" ng-repeat="role in ctrl.userRoles">
      {{role}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```